# Transforming multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be multivariate normal distribution with $ \begin{bmatrix}
\mu_1 \\
\mu_1 
\end{bmatrix}  $and covariance matrix given as$ \begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma \;\Sigma \\
\Sigma \;\lambda \Sigma 
\end{bmatrix}  $where $\lambda > 1$.

I want to find distribution of $Y =  \begin{bmatrix}
X_1 \\
X_2 - X_1 
\end{bmatrix}  $.

**My solution**

First observation that I made is that for $A :=  \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  $ we have that $Y = AX$.

So mean of distribution $Y$ will be given as $$A \begin{bmatrix}
\mu_1 \\
\mu_1 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\mu_1 \\
-\mu_1 + \mu_2
\end{bmatrix}$$

And covariance matrix:

$$A\Sigma_XA^T=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma \;\Sigma \\
\Sigma \;\lambda \Sigma 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma & 0 \\
-1 & \Sigma[-I + \lambda I] 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Does my way of thinking make sense to you?